# How to focus on div and dim background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropdown

I am doing a custom dropdown, which is not necessarily a `select` element because of the `select` element's limitation.

The div should have a dropdown and once the dropdown is displayed, it should focus there and dim the background. It is not a modal, because the dropdown should stay below the other div.

For better understanding, please see the desired output here:

[image]

Hope you could help me on how I should do this.

Comment: You can use [Page dim jquery extension in your project] (https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiWka-W98_RAhXKso8KHWiSDcAQFggZMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmmenu.frebsite.nl%2Fdocumentation%2Fextensions%2Fpage-dim.html&usg=AFQjCNHdNnhjF6SLPI7K4q4zDxATMYondQ&bvm=bv.144224172,d.c2I). This might help you.

Comment: I've seen it. But how do I focus in the dropdown div?

Comment: You want to handle this from jquery and css both. Try adding active class

Answer (score 2):

Upon click of that drop-down change opacity of other elements.

Something like:

```
$('.drop-down').click(function(){
    $('.other-background-div').css('opacity', '0.5');
});
```

Or you can also add a div with z-index on top of other elements but below the drop-down and show hide based on click.

```
$('.drop-down').click(function(){
    $('.new-added-div-with-color-gray').toggle();
});
```

Use whichever solution suits you.